# order of two structures

Tags: c++, c, ansi-c

I have these two structures...

```
typedef struct{
    MY_SECOND_STRUCT  s1;
}MY_FIRST_STRUCT;


typedef struct{
    int s1;
}MY_SECOND_STRUCT;
```

I prefer this order, I dont want to switch them.
But compiler dont know MY_SECOND_STRUCT at the moment and I get error

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MY_SECOND_STRUCT'

I´ve tried add declaration to the top

```
struct MY_SECOND_STRUCT;
```

also change definition to

```
typedef struct{
    struct MY_SECOND_STRUCT  s1;
}MY_FIRST_STRUCT;
```

but it didnt help.

Comment: Other answers here are great.  You may be wondering why you can forward declare the struct and then declare a pointer to it -- the compiler knows the size of the pointer, so it can determine the size of a struct which contains it, but it does not know the size of the second struct, so it can't define a struct which contains that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That order is not possible. You have to switch them.

However, if you declare the member as pointer, then switching is not required:

```
struct MY_SECOND_STRUCT; //forward declaration is required though

typedef struct{
    MY_SECOND_STRUCT  * s1;  //now its a pointer
}MY_FIRST_STRUCT;
```

Or, in C++ you can use template as:

```
template<typename MY_SECOND_STRUCT>
struct MY_FIRST_STRUCT_T
{
    MY_SECOND_STRUCT  s1;
};

struct MY_SECOND_STRUCT
{
    int s1;
};
```

And when you want to use `MY_FIRST_STRUCT`, just use this `typedef`:

```
typedef MY_FIRST_STRUCT_T<MY_SECOND_STRUCT> MY_FIRST_STRUCT;
```

Use `MY_FIRST_STRUCT` now. :-)

Comment: if I declare the member as pointer and add forward declaration as you wrote I still get an error. I have to write 

**struct MY_SECOND_STRUCT  * s1;**

 than its ok. (my compiler gcc)

Comment: @Meloun: That is what I've written. Or are you programming in C? What is the file extension? `.c` or `.cpp`?

Answer (score 8):

> I prefer this order, I dont want to switch them.

You have to switch them.

If `MY_FIRST_STRUCT` has a member variable of type `MY_SECOND_STRUCT` then `MY_SECOND_STRUCT` must be defined and complete (not just declared and incomplete) before the definition of `MY_FIRST_STRUCT`.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you cerate your first struct the compiler hasn't come across the second struct yet. It needs to know how bit `MY_SECOND_STRUCT` is because at that time it needs to decide how big to make `MY_FISRT_STRUCT` and how to lay out the memory for it. Simply forward declaring struct `MY_FIRST_STRUCT` is not enough, that doesn't tell the compiler about the size or contents of the struct. Forward declaring would work if you were using a pointer to a struct, but it's not enough when trying to include the actual structure.

Your only real options are to move `MY_SECOND_STRUCT` up above `MY_FIRST_STRUCT` or to make `MY_FIRST_STRUCT` takes a pointer. It might seem strange at first, but there's not much that can be done about it.